# Asignar valor a una columna dependiendo del valor de otra (pandas)

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas

Tengo una base de datos el cual tengo una columna que etiqueta los tweets entre `misogino` y `no_misogino`. Lo que quiero, es hacer una columna que tenga la etiqueta `0` para `no_misogino` y `1` para `misogino`.

El actual código lo hace, pero al revés. Tengo el siguiente código:

```py
import pandas as pd

Texto_final['Categoria_ID'] = Texto_final['Tipo'].factorize(sort=True)[0]
Categoria_ID_datos = Texto_final[['Tipo', 'Categoria_ID']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('Categoria_ID')
Categoria_a_ID = dict(Categoria_ID_datos.values)
ID_a_Categoria = dict(Categoria_ID_datos[['Categoria_ID', 'Tipo']].values)
Texto_final.head(3)

# Salida incorrecta:
#Tipo        Categoria_ID
#misogino        0
#misogino        0
#no_misogino     1

# Salida deseada:
#Tipo        Categoria_ID
#misogino        1
#misogino        1
#no_misogino     0
```

En resumen, la columna "Tipo" tiene etiquetas de misogino y no_misogino. Quiero crear una columna llamada "Categoria_ID", donde esten valores entre 0 y 1, donde 0 le corresponda no_misogino y 1 para misogino. Pense que solo colocando sort = True se solucionario, pero no.

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Buen día, si entendí bien, ¿Quieres utilizar los datos de la columna `#Tipo` para poner `1` ó `0` en la columna `Categoria_ID`?

Comment: Por cierto `sort` es para ordenar la columna, por ejemplo de mayor a menor

Comment: También agrega un poco más de información sobre las librerías que estas utilizando, había publicado una respuesta con `pandas` pero no sé si lo utilizas o no.

Comment: Una disculpa por la falta de explicación. Ya edite el post, a ver si ya esta mejor así.

Comment: Gracias, recuperé la respuesta que había publicado antes, ahora que sé que utilizas `pandas` la respuesta si aplica para tu caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo único que necesitas es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` como ejemplo en el archivo "sample2.csv"

|  | #Tipo |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | #misogino |
| 1 | #misogino |
| 2 | #no_misogino |
| 3 | #misogino |
| 4 | #no_misogino |
| 5 | #no_misogino |
| 6 | #no_misogino |
| 7 | #no_misogino |
| 8 | #misogino |
| 9 | #misogino |
| 10 | #no_misogino |

Código de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['Categoria_ID'] = df['#Tipo'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='#misogino' else 0)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`

|  | #Tipo | Categoria_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | #misogino | 1 |
| 1 | #misogino | 1 |
| 2 | #no_misogino | 0 |
| 3 | #misogino | 1 |
| 4 | #no_misogino | 0 |
| 5 | #no_misogino | 0 |
| 6 | #no_misogino | 0 |
| 7 | #no_misogino | 0 |
| 8 | #misogino | 1 |
| 9 | #misogino | 1 |
| 10 | #no_misogino | 0 |

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! si me funciono :3

Comment: No hay de que. Recuerda que una pregunta con toda la información y mostrando un esfuerzo por parte del autor ayuda a recibir respuestas rápidamente. Saludos!